user service that needs to wait for logind to finish updating ACLs on "uaccess" tagged devices
I am trying to configure fluidsynth to run as a user service on Debian system. Problem is that it starts on user login and needs access to /dev/snd/seq or it produces an error and turns into a "zombie" (i.e. active, but doesn't really work):
fluidsynth[2404]: ALSA lib seq_hw.c:466:(snd_seq_hw_open) open /dev/snd/seq failed: Permission denied

That access is (eventually) given by udev rule 70-uaccess.rules (executed by 73-seat-late.rules) -- i.e. after login is successful I can restart the service in terminal and everything works.
Is there a way to tell systemd to start my service only after that rule finish executing?
Edit:
Looks like there is no good way to delay user service start until uaccess devices get their ACLs updated. Adding your user to the audio group seems to be the only practical solution...

For the question as stated ("wait for udev rules to finish execution"), you would add a dependency on the corresponding .device unit:
Requires=dev-snd-seq.device
After=dev-snd-seq.device

If there were no .device unit, you'd need to add another udev rule that applies TAG+="systemd" to cause systemd to generate the virtual .device unit.
However, this won't work because your access is not "(eventually) given by udev rule". Udev rules are processed only in response to events on the device itself, so although 73-seat-late.rules calls the udev 'uaccess' builtin to apply initial ACLs to tagged devices, it only happens once when an add event is emitted for that device (much earlier than your login).
The rules for all devices are not re-run when a user logs in, as udev is completely unaware of "user login" events (or any non-device-related events in general). Instead, after the initial udev processing, access is handled by a completely different service – specifically, systemd-logind – which manages the user-seat relationships (sessions) and uses libudev to iterate over all "uaccess"- tagged devices and update their device node ACLs. It does not re-execute any udev rules at this point.
The problem here is that systemd-logind does so only after it has started the user's service manager (since applying ACLs is a 'seat' function, so the code flow has to create a 'user', then a session(user, seat), and only then inform the seat about the newly active session), so your user-level services that are in default.target will likely never see the ACLs update in time. (I see that Fluidsynth 2.x already comes with its own user/fluidsynth.service unit; I'm not sure how it is meant to work, but I kind of suspect it relies on the user being in the audio group and just always having access.)
You might need to have the service be started by another target (e.g. graphical-session), or add an ExecStartPre= that just loops until the device has its ACLs updated.
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "until [ -r /dev/snd/seq ]; do sleep 1; done"


omg, I've spent days torturing google looking for this info :). Now it all makes sense. So, all logind magic happens in parallel to starting user services? Then I don't see why using graphical-session.target instead of default.target can help -- for all I know setting ACLs on uaccess tagged devices can take days and user can log out by then...

basically, is there some sort of event that says "logind finished updating uaccess devices ACLs"? After that event I can run systemctl --user start fluidsynth in a script (instead of enabling it).

default.target is started by logind as part of user setup (i.e. during the CreateSession call); graphical-session.target is started by your display manager when starting the GUI, which only happens after the CreateSession dbus call returns from logind, which means logind will necessarily have finished the ACL processing that was part of CreateSession. There's a D-Bus system bus signal indicating an ActiveSession change on the seat.

Should I use d-bus activated service then? Tbh, I just learned about their existence and have no clue how to use this...

No, D-Bus activation only deals with messages that are directed specifically at that service, whereas signals are broadcast. You could in theory have a regular service that subscribes to that signal and starts fluidsynth (it's maybe 5 lines of Perl or 10 of Python), but I'm not sure how reliable the "simple" implementation will be – what if the service just happens to start after the signal and waits forever (maybe that's impossible for the same reason as in the main answer? I don't know at the moment). Similarly, you could have an ExecStartPre script that waits for the D-Bus signal and exits.

So, the best solution would be WantedBy=graphical-session.target? As I understand it won't work on a system without GUI... Plus it is somewhat cryptic to anyone not privy to this discussion -- that person would be scratching his head "why?".
